# What are the non-game-name qualifier tags for this site?

Tags: support, tags

Arqade tags are inundated with tags based on the names of games.  Secreted within these tags are the actual helper / categorization / qualifier tags, such as [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements), [controllers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controllers) and [terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

There are so many game name tags that they drown out the categorization tags.

Is there a culled list somewhere of the sorts of tags I'm looking for?

Comment: If I had my druthers, nearly all of them would be gone...

Comment: Likely not, short of looking at the entire tag list.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - The title does help group though; if they were all prefixed with title_{rest_of_tag} then that might help keep them separate.  I think sites like this and the movies should have a secondary tag grouping; one for title, the other (standard tags) for categorization.

Comment: @Josh sadly, short of software changes from SE though, they're more useless than useful. :(

Comment: The whole tag SE tag system kind of doesn't work on Arqade as expertise in a field of a game does not translate in expertise in the same field of a different game and, as a result, we have grown to frown upon "field tags".

Comment: I do think categorizing your game titles with... a one-level category tag of "title" would help with searching tags. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87656/root-tags-to-organize-larger-sites-with-multiple-categories

Comment: @badp - you're likely right; somehow Movies & TV tags have been capable to sort their utility tags higher than the title tags through natural process.  While similar in concept, utilities are more generally applicable to film/tv than to game mechanics.

Comment: @JoshDM Tags are sorted by usage, there are no custom tag sorting mechanisms I know of. More likely Movies & TV just uses tags like `plot`, `characters` etc a lot more than we use tags like `controllers`.

Comment: Most of the tags you are looking at are used for making it more specific, rather than more general.  Terminology is likely included from a specific game or genre.  Controllers are likely a subset of the game system, and most of the time the question is still related to a certain game.  Achievements are, for the most part, game specific.